# AEM access component properties inside a dialog

Tags: aem, aem-6

I have following part inside a component dialog:

```
            <imgPreview
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        sling:resourceType="aem-project/components/imgPreview"
                                        baseUrl="https://photo1.com"
                                        name="imgPreview"/>
```

the component has the following property among others:

```
fileReference - String -  https://photo2.com
```

what I want to achieve is something like
`baseUrl=${properties.fileReference}`
the baseUrl to point to the component property.

Is it possible access component property directly inside the dialog ?

Answer (score 1):

You said this **imgPreview** component is inside other component's dialog, then I'll say the name of that "other component" as "**parent**", for convenience.

What you're looking for is how to use **parent**'s "fileReference" property value inside **imgPreview**, right?

I think this is not exact way you were looking for, but I think what you want might be achieved with this way.

Create a js file and write code like this at **parent** component's authoring dialog clientlibs.

> ```
> $(document).on("dialog-ready", function() { 
>     // getting fileReference property value inside parent component's dialog
>     const fileRefEl = $("[name='./fileReference']");
>
>
>     // select the tag to use fileReference value inside imagePreview component
>     const imgPreviewEl = $(tagSelector);
>
>
>     if (fileRefEl && imgPreviewEl) {
>         // use fileReference value as you want
>         // example : imgPreviewEl.attr("src", fileRefEl.val());
>     } 
> });
> ```

You can get the values of **parent** component's properties at js file in authoring dialog clientlibs, and you can pass it into **imgPreview** component's html directly, because you put **imgPreview** inside the dialog.

If you want to know how to use authoring dialog clientlibs, this video might be helpful.

- Adding JS via cq authoring dialog in AEM : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYSRtJXJshk

Comment: thanks for answer, this is also one of the alternative solutions, I did it inside the jsp of the component. The original question is to have baseUrl=${properties.fileReference} in the dialog xml that will access the property directly from crx, which is not possible, so you have to use js or jsp.